# PostgreSQL Using LIKE on an array

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

I have two tables, "tags" and "aliases", where multiple aliases can map to the same tag. I am trying to do a tag search, and I can easily search for tags matching a search query using LIKE, but I also want to make the search query match against any of the aliases of the tag.

This is what I currently have:

```sql
SELECT tags.*, json_agg(DISTINCT aliases.*) AS aliases
FROM tags
FULL JOIN aliases ON aliases.tag = tags.tag
WHERE tags.tag LIKE $1 || '%'
GROUP BY tags.tag
```

How do I use LIKE on each of the aliases (in the json array aliases)?

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer, credit goes to u/DavidGJohnston on Reddit. You can do this by adding an EXISTS subquery.

```sql
SELECT tags.tag, json_agg(DISTINCT aliases.*) AS aliases
FROM tags
FULL JOIN aliases ON aliases.tag = tags.tag
WHERE tags.tag LIKE $1 || '%'
OR EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM aliases
  WHERE aliases.tag = tags.tag 
  AND aliases.alias LIKE $1 || '%'
)
GROUP BY tags.tag
```